# SQL - Perform action for each group of items

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, grouping

For example I have a table

```
| ID | Key | Value |
--------------------
| 1  | a   | 123   |
| 2  | b   | 354   |
| 3  | c   | 980   |
| 4  | b   | 354   |
| 5  | a   | 123   |
```

I want to get groups where `Key` and `Value` are equal. So it will be

```
| 1  | a   | 123   |
| 5  | a   | 123   |
--------------------
| 2  | b   | 354   |
| 4  | b   | 354   |
--------------------
| 3  | c   | 980   |
```

And then for each group I want to perform some action. Something like check some value in another table for each `ID` and set some flag...

I think `GROUP BY` will be useful here, but I have no clue how to achieve what I want.

**EDIT**

If you need example of an action...

Assume I have another table where `ID` is a foreign key.

```
| ID | Name | Address | IsActive |
```

For each group I want to chek if any item in this group have an address, and set `IsActive` to `false` for all other items in this group.

Comment: *And then for each group I want to perform some action* You have to be more specific than that.

Comment: You should note that because your foreign key is ID, you aren't checking if the GROUP has an address, you're checking of the ID has an address. If you want to check that the GROUP has an address, you'll have to have "KEY" and "VALUE" fields in your ADDRESS table so you can join with them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it a bit later, can't do it right now. Also is there any way to do it without having 'Key' and 'Value' fields in 'Address' table?

Comment: Just try my suggestions and see if it yields the desired outcome. If not, post your output and I'll help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Check the ["GROUP BY More Than One Column"](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) part.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(ID INT, [KEY] NVARCHAR(10), VALUE INT)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('1', 'A', '123'), 
( '2',  'b', '354'), 
( '3', 'c', '980'),
('4', 'b', '354'),
('5', 'a', '123')


SELECT ID, [KEY], VALUE
FROM #TEMP 
GROUP BY [KEY], VALUE, ID
```

This achieves the grouping. To perform an action, you need to implement a CASE WHEN to check the table you're joining to.

```
CREATE TABLE #ADDRESS
([ADDRESS] NVARCHAR(25), ID INT)
INSERT INTO #ADDRESS VALUES ('123 MAIN ST', '1')

SELECT A.ID, A.[KEY], A.VALUE,
           CASE WHEN B.[ADDRESS] IS NOT NULL THEN 'ACTIVE' ELSE 'INACTIVE' END AS 'ACTIVE?'
FROM #TEMP A
LEFT JOIN #ADDRESS B
ON A.ID = B.ID
GROUP BY A.[KEY], A.VALUE, A.ID, B.[ADDRESS]
```

Comment: Additionally, your output above is incorrect as there is no '980' in the VALUE field.

Comment: Fixed field with '980'